# adding a field in the schema file gives and error while executing the file

Tags: node.js, mongoose

hi this is the schema file which i have already.

```
 // defining a mongoose schema 
 // including the module 
  var mongoose = require('mongoose'); 
 // declare schema object. 
 var Schema = mongoose.Schema; 

 var blogSchema = new Schema({ 

 title : {type:String,default:'',required:true }, 
  subTitle : {type:String,default:''}, 
 blogBody : {type:String,default:''}, 
 tags   : [],// name of tags in array 
 created    : {type:Date}, 
 lastModified : {type:Date}, 
 authorInfo  :  {} // information of author in form of obje-ct 
 }); 

 mongoose.model('Blog',blogSchema);
```

when i am adding the bewlow two fileds to the files in the schema

```
  userName : {type:String,default:''} ,
  passWord : {type:String,default:''} 

 like

 // defining a mongoose schema 
 // including the module 
 var mongoose = require('mongoose'); 
 // declare schema object. 
 var Schema = mongoose.Schema; 

 var blogSchema = new Schema({ 

 title : {type:String,default:'',required:true}, 
  subTitle : {type:String,default:''}, 
  blogBody : {type:String,default:''}, 
  tags : [],// name of tags in array 
  created : {type:Date}, 
  lastModified : {type:Date}, 
  authorInfo  :  {} // information of author in form of obje-ct 
 userName : {type:String,default:''} ,----------------------------------here
  passWord : {type:String,default:''} ----------------------------------here
 });
```

after saving the file in app.js and running the command node app.js it is 
throwing an error as below, i am running this file even after installing all the packages

```
C:\leveltwo\assigntwo\blogModel.js:19 
  userName        : {type:String,default:''} 
    ^^^^^^^^ 
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 
at createScript (vm.js:56:10) 
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10) 
at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)

 because of the above problem i am unable to create a new entries in the 
 project and even my  postman is also not responding.
 please reply if anyone knows ..... thank you.
```

Comment: You are missing a "comma". `authorInfo  :  {}` should have a comma on the end `authorInfo  :  {},`

Comment: oh thanks@ Neil Lunn .

Comment: but why it is showing error at userName field it can show above the line right.

Comment: Because the "comma" was expected "before" the next line and therefore the "next line" that was not preceded by a comma is the syntax error. That's why it's "not an error" to not use a comma on the "last" line. JavaScript 101 really.